# Read contents of file into pig variable

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

so I have a 1 line file in `adl://storage.azuredatalakestore.net/file.txt` this file contains 1 line.  I need to pass the contents of this file as a parameter

```
%default property 'this is my property';
%default setlfag 'false';
%default headerfile `adl://storage.azuredatalakestore.net/file.txt`;

//Somehow read the contents of $headerfile into $header variable

register myjar.jar
DEFINE Wrap com.Main('$property', '$header', '$setflag');
```

Where `$header` should just be the first line of the file(the file is only 1 line long).  How would I accomplish this? I have been searching for about 1/2 a day and found absolutely nothing on this topic.

Note: The file needs to be read in pig , I cannnot edit the jar.

Comment: `header = LOAD 'file.txt';` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @cricket_007 that puts a leading and trailing `(` and `)` into the string.   So, it would be like `(....filecontents....)` when all I want is `....filecontents.....`.  I just need the contents of `file.txt` as a single string.